# How to decrease footer height in wordpress using css?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to decrease footer height  in my wordpress page using css. i have tried it but the result is not what i wanted. The footer add little space below it.

i have tried use transform : scale, padding-bottom (this one does not work), height, etc.

```
#wrap_footer{
    position : relative;
    height : 60px;
}
```

i just want the footer height decrease and not add any space below it.

[this is the original page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvV0z.png)

[this is a photo that shows the footer results that I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxGji.png)

Thanks

Comment: I went to your page and used this #footer-bottom .pad.group{height: 60px; padding: 0 30px;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;}

Comment: how can you get that? I did not find it in the inspector.

Comment: btw, thanks you help me out

Answer (score 0):

you may use this css style in:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think this will make my footer following my page scrolling up and down.
btw, the probelm solved..thanks for comment.